# Callback method processResponse() not called if endpoint is an invalid website

Tags: continuation

I am using Apex Continuation which has 2 functions:
`startRequest()` - the starting function
`processResponse()` - the callback function.

### Problem

`processResponse()` is being called OK either...

1. when I get a Response OR
2. when the Continuation times out (number of seconds are given in the parameter).

However, `processResponse()` is not called when HttpRequest Endpoint is an invalid website (even after the timeout is reached).

How to handle Apex Continuation when the endpoint is an invalid website?

```
    public Object startRequest()
    {
        // Create continuation with a timeout
        Continuation con = new Continuation(40); //40 seconds
        // Set callback method
        con.continuationMethod='processResponse';
        // Create callout request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(testDataUrl);
        // Add callout request to continuation
        this.requestLabel = con.addHttpRequest(req);
        // Return the continuation
        return con;  
    }

    // Callback method 
    public Object processResponse()
    {
        // Get the response by using the unique label
        HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel);
        if(response != null && response.getBody() != null && response.getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
        }
        else
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample endpoint? I have provided a fake endpoint and it gives me 400 error.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal any invalid website should do. If you are getting a 400 error, there is something wrong in my VF then. Checking...

Comment: I checked... nothing wrong with my Class and VF because I copied the example (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm) from Salesforce and simply put in a URL in the placeholder. I am not getting a response code for any invalid URL such as http://www.fill1text.com/ but getting a response 200 from http://www.filltext.com/